# In Unity3d my Score doesnt work without hardcoding the if Statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

So my problem is that the players x postion = to the score he reached. But i want to turn the counter off after an specific amount got reached. My problem is I cant do the If Statement without hardcoding the comparing value.

```
//public text value for the Text
    public Text scoreText;
    //Takes the player Transform
    public Transform player;

    public int bossFightMeter = 2000;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {   //compares the postion on x with an value (check how to solv it without hard coding it)
        if (player.position.x < bossFightMeter) 
        {
            //The X postion of the player is converted to string and displayed on the Text output 
            scoreText.text = player.position.x.ToString("0");   //set to 0 so it counts in full numbers
        }
    }
```

if I write

```
if(player.position.x < 2000)
{
   ...
}
```

then it actully works but i dont wanna hardcode it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bossFightMeter variable is set to public. Check in the unity inspector if its value is 2000. If you have changed the value inside of the code but not in inspector, the code will take inspector's value to be used. You can either make that variable private or always set the value that you want in the inspector or set its value in void start().

Answer (score 0):

I actully just found out the reason it doesnt count is the .ToString("0");. But if I change it to .ToString(); then the Score doesnt count in whole numbers. How do i change that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still keep the Score counting in whole numbers, you can round the number before you assign them to the score.

You can use the `Math.Round` method for that which you need to assign three parameters for:

1. The value you want to round.
2. The number of decimals you want to keep after the value.
3. An optional parameter you can invoke to use `AwayFromZero` rounding.
   (ignored unless rounding is ambiguous, e.g. 1.5)

**Sample code:**

```cs
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{   
    //compares the postion on x with the bossFightMeter
    if (player.position.x < bossFightMeter) 
    {
        // The X postion of the player is rounded to the nearest full number
        var rounded = Math.Round(player.position.x, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        // Set text to be the rounded number.
        scoreText.text = rounded.ToString();
    }
}
```

`AwayFromZero` rounds 1.5 to 2 which doesn't happen without `AwayFromZero`.

Comment: Thank you for the help but putting the value to private worked already :D.